# position().left isn't giving the expected value

Tags: javascript, jquery, position

In the employee section of a Wordpress site, I'm trying to have the bio slide open in the correct position when you click on each employee photo.

It's working well when the row is full width (4 columns) and in mobile (1 column) but in the 2 column layout (480px to 882px), position().left is returning 0, so the negative margin isn't being properly applied and the bio goes offscreen.

I can't for the life of me figure out why this is... Any help is greatly appreciated!

The site in question: http://contractor-marketing.website/

The HTML (simplified):

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="column column_1">
    <!--content-->
    <div class="bio-full"><!--content--></div>
  </div>
  <div class="column column_2">
    <!--content-->
    <div class="bio-full"><!--content--></div>
  </div>
  <div class="column column_3">
    <!--content-->
    <div class="bio-full"><!--content--></div>
  </div>
  <div class="column column_4">
    <!--content-->
    <div class="bio-full"><!--content--></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The JS:

```
jQuery('.column').each(function(s, el) {
  jQuery(this).find('.bio-full').eq(0).css('margin-left',-(jQuery(el).position().left));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Check my example below. Although I took a different approach, it essentially does what you want, and it even animates the element transition.

NOTE: This animation will happen EACH time you press the animate button. You must prevent such animation from happening more than once (if that is the behavior you are looking for). Also, change the `$('#animate')` selector and `click` event to the event of your choice.

```js
$('#animate').click(function() {
  $(".bio-full").animate({
    left: "+=300",
  }, 1000, function() {
    // Animation complete.
  });
});
```

```css
body{
  padding:0;
  margin:0;
}
.bio-full{
  background-color: red;
  display:hidden;
  position:relative;
  width:300px;
  left:-300px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="animate">Animate</button>
<div class="row">
  <div class="column column_1">
    <!--content-->
    <div class="bio-full"><h1>Profile</h1></div>
  </div>
  <div class="column column_2">
    <!--content-->
    <div class="bio-full"><h1>Profile</h1></div>
  </div>
  <div class="column column_3">
    <!--content-->
    <div class="bio-full"><h1>Profile</h1></div>
  </div>
  <div class="column column_4">
    <!--content-->
    <div class="bio-full"><h1>Profile</h1></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I hope this helps!

Cheers!

Comment: That's just a copying error when I simplified the HTML. Fixed now in my original question.

Comment: Thanks for the response. The margin/left can't be hardcoded... it depends on screen size. If you check out the website and click any of the bios in the right hand column, you can see them going offscreen. Basically, I just want to know why position().left is returning 0 for these instead of the offset distance of its parent (the row).